# MoveIt visual tools demo (visual_tools_demo.launch ) is not wotrking

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed all the needed dependencies for running the MoveIt visual tools demo: visual_tools_demo.launch.

It seems that the figures are published, but they are nor showed in rviz.

The error message that I receive seems to be that the message published type is not the same as the listener is waiting for, but it is debatable, see the attached image Terminal.​

This is the error:

**[ERROR] [1460471289.382908506]: Client [/rviz_myuser_8324064928412942903] wants topic /moveit_visual_tools to have datatype/md5sum [visualization_msgs/Marker/18326976df9d29249efc939e00342cde], but our version has [visualization_msgs/MarkerArray/90da67007c26525f655c1c269094e39f]. Dropping connection.**

**This is the error image** [image: image description](/upfiles/14604709696160995.png)

**The rviz config image**[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231745/moveit-visual-tools-demo-(visual_tools_demo.launch-)-is-not-wotrking/) by [pablocesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20992/pablocesar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2016-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this is a really late answer, but for others stumbling upon this kind of question. The error message indicates that the topic contains the right message type, but the version and thus the md5 checksum are different. This means that Rviz and moveit_visual_tools were build using different versions of the message.

Probably the moveit visual tools messages are newer as they are built from source and rviz probably isn't. You can compare the checksums yourself by running the command `rosmsg md5 visualization_msgs/Marker`. Running this command after you have sourced the ros installation (/opt/ros/ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash) and once after you have source the workspace should let you know if this is indeed the case.

Solving this issue requires one of the two programs to use the older messages. You could build the older messages in the workspace or building rviz from source.

---

Originally posted by [pvl](https://answers.ros.org/users/74901/pvl/) with karma: 111 on 2021-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0